# Multiple string comparison

Tags: c, string, compare

I need to compare 3 strings to 1 string.
I am currently using the code below. The `seatclass` is entered by the user.

```
 char first[10] = "FC";
 char econ[10] = "EC";
 char eandf[10]= "FC&EC";

     if ((seatclass==first)||(seatclass==econ)||(seatclass==eandf))
      {
      printf("win");
      }
      else
      {      
      printf("This is not a seatclass choose again");
      getchar(); 
      }
```

However when I enter `FC` or any other random value I always get
`This is not a seatclass choose again`

Comment: What language is this? Please tag your question with the appropriate language.

Comment: This is the C language

Comment: Then update your question and add the "c" tag. By the way, string comparison in c is performed using `strcmp`.

Comment: Can you give example in code with 3 strings compared to 1 string

Comment: Just use `||`, as you're already doing. Note that `c#` is not `c`!

Comment: Be carefull the tag is important, your code is "C" and not "C#".

Comment: Replace the `if` with `if(strcmp(seatclass,first)==0 || strcmp(seatclass,econ)==0 || strcmp(seatclass,eandf)==0)` and don't forget to include `string.h`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare in C.

Here is how you can do the comparison :

```
char first[10] = "FC";
char econ[10] = "EC";
char eandf[10]= "FC&EC";

if (strcmp(seatclass,first)==0 || strcmp(seatclass,econ)==0 || strcmp(seatclass,eandf)==0)
{
    printf("win");
}
else
{
    printf("This is not a seatclass choose again");
    getchar();
}
```

NOTE : You can use '==' to compare [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) in C++

Answer (score 1):

The response is that the "`==`" operator is comparing pointers in your case you should use the `strncmp` function ([from string.h](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcmp))

Answer (score 1):

"==" will point to the memory addres in case of arrays and strings in C..instead you can use strcmp function.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two strings, we can use the `strcmp()` or `strncmp()` functions.

Answer (score -1):

Using a `strcmp()` function we can compare the hole string, Using the `strncmp()` function we can compare the some specific range of the string.

The both functions return `0` if the string is same, else it return `-1 or 1`